# Спарсить строку

Tags: gson, строки, java, синтаксический-анализ

Привет всем! Имеется вот такая сложная строка:

```
[{
    "Group1": [{"id": "2b3b0db","name": "Ivan"}, {"id": "4f3b0db","name": "Lera"}]},
{"Group2": [{"id": "42ae2a7", "name": "Victor"}]}]
```

Как мне ее спарсить? Извлечь id, name. Обычно делал так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Parse[] p = gson.fromJson(result, Parse[].class);
```

В классе Parse - переменные которые надо спарсить. Но строка была без двойных вложений. Спасибо!

Comment: Значение ключей group1 и group2, могут быть динамическими вроде group100500, или все эти ключи описаны в классе Parse ?

Comment: нет. значения груп1 и груп2 - постоянные. в классе Parse у меня пока ничего не описано, потому что я понятия не имею как спарсить подобную строку.

Comment: Тогда Вас нужно нечто вроде:  

    class User {
        public String id;
        public String name;
    }
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,User[]>> al= gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String,User[]>>>(){}.getType());
Не могу протестировать к сожалению, дам наводку просто в каком направлении мыслить.

Comment: как юзать это все дело еще бы написали. :)

Comment: В al теоретически будет ArrayList в котором будет HashMap в которой ключ String и значение User[]. Сериализация/десериализация такой структуры будет приводить к JSON такого вида.

Answer (score 1):

Делаю обычно так, никогда не было проблем.

```
    try{
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray( url );
        for( int i=0; i<result.length(); i++ )
        {
            JSONObject itemJsonObject = result.getJSONObject( i );
            JSONArray itemArrayGroup = itemJsonObject.getJSONArray( "Group" + i );
            for( int j=0; j<itemArrayGroup.length();j++ )
            {
                String cID = itemArrayGroup.getJSONObject(j).getString("id");
                String cName = itemArrayGroup.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
                anyAction( cID , cName );
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        Log.d("error","error : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я немного не уточнил. Внутри каждой группы может быть много объектов. Тогда как быть? Примерно так: { "Group1": [{"id": "2b3b0db", "name": "Ivan"}, {"id": "2b3b0db", "name": "Gloriya"}]}

Comment: Изменил код, недоглядел что Group это массив, а не обьект